# Sending mail by setting recipient address in setHeader() method - java mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-headers

Is there any way to add Recipient address using setHeader() like

```
message.setHeader("To:","mail@domain.com");
```

I tried the above one and it is not working. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I need an alternative for the following code:

```
InternetAddress mail_to = new InternetAddress("mail_id@domain.com","Name_of_recipient");
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, mail_to);
```

My requirement is to skip RFC822 email format check.

Comment: Would it not be easier just to write your own Address subclass? The .addRecipient() method just accepts an Address, and the RFC822 checking is done in the InternetAddress subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The header name is "To", without the colon.

But you're not going to get very far with an incorrectly formatted address.  Even if JavaMail doesn't detect the error, the server most likely will.